# Umbraco - Get Directory of Config Files

Tags: asp.net, windows, umbraco

I'm working with Umbraco 4.7.1 and I've created some extensions that hook into Document.AfterPublish and Document.AfterUnPublish.  I need to find the directory of the config files from here, but need to be independent of server installation (i.e. a literal won't work).  Is there any way of finding this at that point in time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the `umbraco.IO.SystemDirectories` class, specifically the `Config` property.

This will return "~/config" by default, but can be overridden by adding a `umbracoConfigDirectory` key to the `appSettings` section of the web.config file and specifying a different path there.